# Ubuntu startup problem

Tags: boot, disk-management

I am using Ubuntu, I start up my computer and see the following message.
Keys: Press F to attempt to fix the errors, I to ignore, S to skip mounting, or M for manual recovery.

Comment: Sounds like bad sectors on your hard drive. What happens when you press f and attempt to fix the errors?

Comment: I pressed the button to shutdown my computer, I do not remember last night. Today I have this problem. When I press F I have following message.. *Stopping read required file in advance *Starting Mount fileSystems on boot * Starting Populate and link to /run filesystem and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using windows 8 or 8.1 you might want to disable fast start-up, go to this link to know how to disable it: http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-disable-or-enable-fast-startup-in-windows-8-1/
if you are using any windows and you are switching to ubuntu after hibernate or improper/forced shutdown then first boot to windows and restart windows, instead of booting to windows again, boot to ubuntu.
let me know if you have any problem